# Checking if username already exists within the databasae

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, validation

i am trying to check against the database table "user" to see if the "username" exists so that the same username cannot be created again. I want this to be a validator so if the username exists the message box will show it exists.

Please guide me through this, i have the following code so far behind the button to add and check if username exists:

```
private void btnSignupNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (txtUsername.Text == "")
           {
               errorUsername.SetError(txtUsername, "Enter A Username");
           }

           else if (txtPassword.Text == "")
           {
               errorPassword.SetError(txtPassword, "Enter A Valid Password");
           }

               //so if there isnt no error in the fields itll go on and add the data in to the database.
           else{

            //instance of sqlConnection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=etc");

            //instance of sqlCommand
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values ('" + txtForename.Text + "', '" + txtSurname.Text + "', '" + txtUsername.Text + "', '" + txtPassword.Text + "' )", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //query executed correcty or not
           con.Close();
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) for prevent _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: I would suggest that you should query the user table to see if the username already exists, but before you do that you should google for 'sql injection' and make your queries parameterised.

Comment: Have a look at IF EXISTS in sql and yes @SLaks is right you have a SQL injection vulnerability although this isnt related to the question you might want to know

Comment: hi guys thanks for the advice about SQL injection vulnerabilities, but as this is just a simple application i am creating for myself i dont think it matters about that.

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) FROM blah) THEN INSERT INTO [User] ...

Comment: Look at your own code, you haven't written anything that queries the database. Only an insert. Nor have you tested for an error on insert which is what you should get if the database column had a UNIQUE constraint (which would be much better than checking in your code). In general your question should have both what you tried, and what result you got when you ran your code.

Comment: Stack Overflow follows a strict Q&A format and you don't really have a question here, just "please guide me through this." Can you edit your post to ask a specific, detailed question?

Comment: if you got no solutions please dont get involved. Thank You. *cough* Gus *cough* dgvid *cough* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a good pratice, try to keep your persistence using `Parameters` to avoid SQL Injection.

Try something liek this:

```
private void btnSignupNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (txtUsername.Text == "")
   {
       errorUsername.SetError(txtUsername, "Enter A Username");
   }
   else if (txtPassword.Text == "")
   {
       errorPassword.SetError(txtPassword, "Enter A Valid Password");
   }
   else
   {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=etc")) 
        {
            con.Open();

            bool exists = false;

            // create a command to check if the username exists
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [User] where UserName = @UserName", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
                exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

            // if exists, show a message error
            if (exists)
                errorPassword.SetError(txtUsername, "This username has been using by another user.");
            else 
            {
                            // does not exists, so, persist the user
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values (@Forname, @Surname, @Username, @Password)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Forname", txtForname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", txtSurname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", txtPassword.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }               
            }

            con.Close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: this works thanks! but i have a slight problem if the username exists i get the error message, but as i have clicked the button "signup" it'll take me back to the login page. any idea how to diffuse this? thanks. by the way the code i have at the bottom is :            MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Signed Up");
           Form1 signin = new Form1();
           signin.Show();
           this.Close();
       }
   }

Comment: It is just about he validation the user. your problem sounds like a authentication problem, and it could be in another thread to avoid extend this one. If you are changing an existent user you could change your query to something like `... Where UserName=@UserName And Id <> @Id"` to avoid checking an existent user.