# username still clears if it already exists

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

here is my code, it is for a login system, very basic, simply writes usernames and passwords to a text file, then compares them on the login screen on another form. This is the register user code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public bool radioButtons()
    {
        if (!userRadioButton.Checked && !adminRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool a = radioButtons();
        if (a == true)
        {
            string userName = userNameBox.Text;
            string password = passwordBox.Text;
            var userNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");
            if (checkUsernameValid() && checkUsernameNotExist() && checkPasswordsValid() && checkPasswordsMatch())
            {
                allOK();
            }


        }   
    } 
    public void mySW()
    {
         string path = @"C:\Other\myFile.txt";
        string userName = userNameBox.Text;
        string password = passwordBox.Text;
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Username and Password: {0} {1}",userName,password);
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering! \n\nYou may now log in!","Registration SuccessFul");
        Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    public bool checkUsernameValid()
    {
        if (userNameBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username cannot be empty", "Invalid Username Entry");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public bool checkPasswordsMatch()
    {
        if (!passwordBox.Text.Equals(repeatPasswordBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, your passwords do not match, try again", "Password Error");
            passwordBox.Text = "";
            repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public bool checkUsernameNotExist()
    {
        if (userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, that user name is not available, try again", "Invalid Username Entry");
            userNameBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
            repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public void allOK()
    {
        if (!userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text) && passwordBox.Text == repeatPasswordBox.Text)
            {
                mySW();
            }
    }
    public bool checkPasswordsValid()
    {
        if (passwordBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password fields cannot be empty", "Password Error");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

   }
}
```

If i enter a username, it does all the checks and registers BUT, it still allows me to register a username if it already exists???

Comment: Shouldn't you be [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function‎) those passwords?

Comment: as you can see in the code, the program outputs the user name and password to C:\Other\myFile.txt if successful. But as i said, you can register with a username, then register a different password or person with the same username

Comment: `if (userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text))` What do you think that does?

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.  Use PBKDFv2.

Comment: i should really, if i had the time to learn i would make it a lot more secure, but to be honest its just for a local application that will be run only by a few company staff, its not a vital thing that the passwords are protected. The most effort required really is that a hidden folder me made to keep the password file in

Comment: well i thought that when i looked at it, i dont know why ive put that, but ive just migrated all my functions to their own methods and the user part came up red, so i corrected it without thinking. the thing is, i dont know how to correct it without moving them all back to how they were...

Comment: @user2827904 Check your `Checkusernamenotexist()` method i think thats where the problem is coming from

Comment: @SLaks SHA-3 is a good candidate.

Comment: just looking at it now, surely if (userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text)) will never verify, thus always returning false, because it will never contain itself plus extra text ("Username: "), it would be a neverending loop, wouldnt it?

Comment: ok, so how would i check the file doest contain the username?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text))
```

I am confused this line . ( this line give any time same result like `True` )

But i give one idea for you

. Store registered values in a DataBase , Then second time the user give same user name , Then  check the username already exist by using sql query .

See this prevoius disscussion : [Checking if username already exists within the databasae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118294/checking-if-username-already-exists-within-the-databasae)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a richtextBox, called 'userlist'. Set the visible to false, and make sure you clear it first.

```
 public bool checkUsernameNotExist()
    {
        string readfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
        userlist.Text = readfile;
        for (int i = 0; i < userlist.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = userlist.Lines[i];
            if (line.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, that user name is not available, try again", "Invalid Username Entry");
                userNameBox.Text = "";
                passwordBox.Text = "";
                repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
```

You can encrypt/decrypt the username by doing this:

```
void encrypt()
{
string encrypted = "";
string encryptstr = yourtextBox.Text;
int encryptnum = 15; //The bigger the number, the stronger the encryption
char[] toencrypt = encryptstr.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < toencrypt.Length; i++)
int num = Convert.ToInt32(toencrypt[i]) + encryptnum;
string output = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString();
encrypted += output;
}

void decrypt() 
{
string decrypted = "";
string decryptstr = yourtextBox.Text;
int decryptnum = 15; //This must be the same as you used to encrypt
char[] todecrypt = decryptstr.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < todecrypt.Length; i++)
int num = Convert.ToInt32(todecrypt[i]) - decryptnum;
string output = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString();
decrypted += output;
}
```

Hope this helps