# method wont check file for matching string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public bool radioButtons()
    {
        if (!userRadioButton.Checked && !adminRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool a = radioButtons();
        if (a == true)
        {
            string userName = userNameBox.Text;
            string password = passwordBox.Text;
            if (checkUsernameValid() && checkUsernameNotExist() && checkPasswordsValid() && checkPasswordsMatch())
            {
                allOK();
            }


        }   
    } 
    public void mySW()
    {
         string path = @"C:\Other\myFile.txt";
        string userName = userNameBox.Text;
        string password = passwordBox.Text;
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(userName+" "+password);
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering! \n\nYou may now log in!","Registration SuccessFul");
        Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    public bool checkUsernameValid()
    {
        if (userNameBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username cannot be empty", "Invalid Username Entry");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public bool checkPasswordsMatch()
    {
        if (!passwordBox.Text.Equals(repeatPasswordBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, your passwords do not match, try again", "Password Error");
            passwordBox.Text = "";
            repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public bool checkUsernameNotExist()
    {
        var userNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");
        if (userNames.Contains(userNameBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                 "Sorry, that user name is not available, try again",
                 "Invalid Username Entry");

            userNameBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
            repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    public void allOK()
    {
        if (!userNameBox.Text.Contains("Username: " + userNameBox.Text) && passwordBox.Text == repeatPasswordBox.Text)
            {
                mySW();
            }
    }
    public bool checkPasswordsValid()
    {
        if (passwordBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password fields cannot be empty", "Password Error");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

   }
}
```

is the full code, but ive been looking over it. I still cant figure out why its letting me register the same username???? i dont understand how its saying "yes, theres a matching string" in the debugger, so lets return true?!

NOTE : I have managed to sort it with ReadAllText, instead of ReadAllLines,  but i dont understand why lines didnt work? anyone have any idea?

PS This code, is there an easier, more secure way of doing it? all i want is a simple login screen lol

Comment: the rest of the code can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078280/username-still-clears-if-it-already-exists but this method has been updated, plus no-one answers after 10 minutes if you have any more questions :(

Comment: Use a debugger so you'll be able to see what exactly is in `userNameBox.Text` and what gets read from the file.

Comment: What are the sample `myFile` and your `input`? Your problem is not in the code you posted (although even the code you posted has something wrong)

Comment: myFile is the plain text file the usernames are written to. The input is from a textbox on the form. the full code is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078280/username-still-clears-if-it-already-exists but this method has been updated, as far as i know the rest still stands...

Comment: I wish to know if this method returns true or not. You should know it because in case of false you have a message box shown. If it returns true then the problem is not in this method

Comment: apparently var userNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt"); says null, meaning the text file is empty? but i just looked at it and it contains text???

Comment: debugger says true, but like i said, the debugger also tells me var userNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt"); is null, but the file contains text?

Comment: my bad, following on the debugger it says userNames contains {string[10]}. so the program finds it contains the string, so it should show the message box, why does it return true???

Comment: @user2827904 your code only worked as you expected if **at least one line in your file exactly matches the `userNameBox.Text`**

Comment: i dont understand. i have just typed the exact same information in and it still registered?

Comment: @user2827904 even the `case-sensitivity` should be considered.

Comment: everything is considered, these are the 2 lines from the file : 
anth qw

anth qw

Comment: @user2827904 see my answer, It should work now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38276/discussion-between-user2827904-and-king-king)

Answer (score 0):

Try trim `userNameBox.Text`from trailing and leading whitespaces. Also, there might be upper lower case differences.

Good idea can be to actually **debug** the code, see what the list contains and what is the value in the text box....

Comment: it says something about overlading arguments if i add it so it says userNameBox.Text.Trim?

Answer (score 0):

File.[readAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) returns a string[] object which in turn doesn't have a Contains method.

I guess, using "var" as datatype allows C# VM to cast it to a String. I would suggest you to specify clearly the datatype expected from readAllLines, otherwise you could replace the call to readAllLines with a call to readAllText.

[readAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) returns a single string with all the contained text.

Answer (score 0):

There shoul be ! in `!userNames.Contains` and better to use Trim() just because of can posibility to enter space by user.

```
if (!userNames.Contains(userNameBox.Text.Trim()))
    {                
        MessageBox.Show(
             "Sorry, that user name is not available, try again",
             "Invalid Username Entry");

        userNameBox.Text = "";
        passwordBox.Text = "";
        repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
```

Comment: what? but that would mean (if usernames doesnt contain the text, then execute screen to say its already taken)???

Comment: This seems to be OK but the method name is `checkUsernameNotExist` not `checkUsernameExist`. The OP should change the name accordingly to make it semantical.

Comment: ok, but even still, that code is saying if the username does not exist already, dont allow user to create it? thats the oppposite of my goal

Answer (score 0):

Try if it works now

```
bool _ans;
public bool checkUsernameNotExist()
{
    string[] userNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt");
    foreach (string name in userNames)
    {
        if (name != userNameBox.Text)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show(
                 "Sorry, that user name is not available, try again",
                 "Invalid Username Entry");

            userNameBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
            repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
            _ans = false;
            return false;
        }
        else
            _ans = true;
            return true;
    }
    return _ans;
}
```

Comment: @user2827904 Are you sure. What errors?. I tried this and it works

Comment: invalid expression term (!=), )expected, among others. what is ==!=?

Comment: @user2827904 (!=) Means `NOT EQUAL TO` and which line did i write `==!=`?

Answer (score 0):

After you posted the full code, the problem is **clear**, each line in your file is written as `username password` (not only `username`). So your code should be like this:

```
public bool checkUsernameNotExist()
{
    bool exist = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Other\myFile.txt")
                     .Any(x=>x.StartsWith(userNameBox.Text+" "));
    if (exist)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
             "Sorry, that user name is not available, try again",
             "Invalid Username Entry");

        userNameBox.Text = "";
        passwordBox.Text = "";
        repeatPasswordBox.Text = "";
    }
    return !exist;
}
```