# Check if user exists in SQL Server user table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a registration form. This code should stop the registration if there is a duplicate of username.

I actually copied this on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118294/checking-if-username-already-exists-within-the-databasae) tried to modify it on my own so I could somehow learn how it works.

Here is my code:

```
private void register_user()
{
    con.Open();

    bool exist = false;

    // Command that checks if username exist
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users1 WHERE Username = '@username'", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtRegUsername.Text);

    exist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

    // If user exist gives error
    if (exist == true)
        lblResults.Text = "Username already exist!";
    else 
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO users1 (Fname, Lname, Mname,
                                                   Username, Password, email, user_type)
                               VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @middle_name,
                                       @username, @password, @email, @user_type)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtFname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", txtLname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle_name", txtMi.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtRegUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtRegPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", "user");

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

My problem is that my code allows the registration of **Username** which already exist. Overall its working.

Comment: you can set unique constraint on username (in database) and then catch the exception

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users1 WHERE Username = '@username'
```

use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users1 WHERE Username = @username
```

Otherwise that's not a parameter but a static value for `Username`.

Side note: I would not count records if I want to know if something exists.

This is more efficient:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users1 WHERE Username = @username)
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS DoesUserExist
```

Comment: Great recommendation to use `IF EXISTS()` instead of counting over potentially millions of users, just to find out whether one particular user already exists

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.. Hope this will help you.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users1 WHERE upper(Username) = upper(@username)", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

exist is  false then you return the value of the SelectCount.

I would do something as

```
If((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0)
{
exist=true;
}
```

Also remove the  ' ' from @username on the query as others said.